# Problem in conceiving the derivation of 'Limit of Sequence to Zero Distance Point'.

Tags: real-analysis

I was following the derivation of '[Limit of Sequence to Zero Distance Point](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sequence_to_Zero_Distance_Point)'; here is the excerpt of the derivation:

> First it is shown that: $$\forall n \in \mathbb N_{>0}: \exists x_n \in S: \left|{\xi - x_n}\right| < \dfrac 1 n$$
>
> Suppose the contrary that $$\exists n \in \mathbb N_{>0}: \not \exists x \in S: \left|{\xi - x}\right| < \dfrac 1 n$$
>
> Then $\dfrac1n$ is a **lower bound** of the set $T=\{|\xi−x|:x\in S\}.$
>
> This contradicts the assertion that $\mathrm d(\xi,S)=0.$
>
> We have from Power of Reciprocal that: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n=0$$
>
> So as $|\xi−x_n|<\dfrac1n,$ it follows from the Squeeze Theorem that: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=\xi$$

I didn't get how $\frac1n$ is the lower bound of $T\ _;$ just because there is no such $x$ for $n$ such that $|\xi - x|\lt \dfrac1n,$ how does it make $\frac1n$ as the lower bound of $T\;?$

Also, how did they use the Squeeze theorem to get $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=\xi\;?$

Could anyone please help me explaining these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The derivation didn't carry the negation of the quantified statement all the way through. In particular, the statement $\lnot(\exists x\in S\,\,|\xi-x|<\frac{1}{n})$ is equivalent to $\forall x\in S\,\,|\xi-x|\geq\frac{1}{n}$. Do you see now why $\frac{1}{n}$ is a lower bound for $T$?
2. Since $0\leq|\xi-x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$, the squeeze theorem says $x_n\to\xi$ as $n\to\infty$.